# How would i make my bot delete commands after use Discord JS

Tags: javascript, discord.js

how would i make my bot delete commands after type like says say  do !kick  and it deletes that command how would i do that? and it deletes its response after 5 seconds? what i have below is what i got so far

````js
const Discord = require("discord.js")

module.exports = {
    name: 'kick',
    usage: '%kick <mention> <reason>',
    description: 'kicks members',

    async execute(client, message, args) {
        if (!message.member.hasPermission("KICK_MEMBERS")) return;
        if (!message.guild.me.hasPermission("KICK_MEMBERS")) return message.reply(`You do not have permission to kick`);
        let member = message.mentions.members.first() || await message.guild.members.cache.get(args[0])
        if (!member) return message.reply("Please @ someone for me to kick")
        let reason = args.slice(1).join(" ");
        if (!reason) reason = "No reason Given";
        if (member.id === message.author.id) return message.reply(`You cannot kick yourself!`)

        const embed = new Discord.MessageEmbed()
            .setTitle('You have been kicked')
            .setDescription(`You have been kicked from **${message.guild.name}** for **${reason}**`)
            .setTimestamp()
            .setAuthor(client.user.tag, client.user.displayAvatarURL())
            .setColor("#6495ED")

        if (member.kickable) {
            member.send(embed).catch(error => message.channel.send(`Couldn't Message mentioned user!`))
                .then(m => member.kick(reason));
            message.channel.send(`**${member.user.tag}** has been kicked!`)
        } else {
            message.reply(`Couldn't kick Mentioned user`);
        }
    }
}```
````

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `message` object that initiated the command has a delete method, so doing `message.delete()` would work from there.

For deleting your response, you first have to wait for the response to send, and then carry out deleting it afterwards.  You can either do this via `.then()` such as:

```
message.channel.send(`**${member.user.tag}** has been kicked!`).then(msg => msg.delete({timeout: 5000})
```

Or, if you want to use async/await:

```
const msg = await message.channel.send(`**${member.user.tag}** has been kicked!`)
msg.delete({timeout: 5000})
```

Full docs for `message.delete()` can be found [here!](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/Message?scrollTo=delete)

Answer (score 0):

I can't remember the hierarchy of an embed, but I know that doing:
`message.delete(time in milliseconds)` will delete the original command message (in your case being !kick)

I think doing `embed.message.delete(time)` or `embed.delete(time)` should delete the embed. I haven't used **discord.js** in forever though so don't quote me on that.

Comment: As of v12, the timeout in ms is now an option and not a parameter